# How to create a process monitor?

Tags: java

I need your help solving a problem in my code. The program is supposed to compare to JTables and delete all matching records. A progress monitor also should show progress of work. My problem is with the progress bar. It is really not working properly. I need your help in solving this. Below is my excerpt of my code:

```
//An inner class
class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        int progress = 0;
        setProgress(0);
        while (progress < table2.getRowCount() && !isCancelled()) {
            //Make progress.
            for( int i= 0;i < table2.getRowCount(); i++){
                    progress =i/10;
                    setProgress(progress);
                for(int j= 0;j < table1.getRowCount();j++){
                    //check if reference nos match
                    if((table2.getValueAt(i,4).toString()).equals(getTrimedValueAt(j))){
                         matchedRefNo++;
                        //if ref matches, then check amount -compareValues(6,1)
                        if(compareValues(j,i)){
                            System.out.println("Value match");
                            matchedValueNo++;
                            deleteRow(i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void done() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        btnStart.setEnabled(true);
        progressMonitor.setProgress(0);
        progressMonitor.close();
        System.out.println("Refereces matced="+matchedRefNo+"\n Values matched "+matchedValueNo);
      }


//and int action performed method
   progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(MainForm.this,
                                  "Scanning files.....",
                                  "", 0, 100);
            progressMonitor.setProgress(0);
            task = new Task();
            task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            task.execute();
    }
```

Comment: In doInBackground(), you havea a while loop that runs while progress < rowCount. Since progress will never get to rowCount (the max progress is rowCount / 10), the loop will never exit. Next, you have a call to setProgress(). What does that do? Can you post that code. Why do you use that instead of progressMonitor.setProgress()?

Comment: thanks so much. I changed the setProgress() to progressMonitor.setProgress() and it now working just fine. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would look is the `break;` in the if statement. You shouldn't need to include that and my thought is that is breaking you out of the loop.

What isn't working properly? Do you have error messages?

Comment: the progress bar is the one that is not working properly. It never stops and keep runing.

Comment: That sounds like you have an infinite loop. Try checking each of the loops to make sure things are being incremented etc. iheanyi commented on your question pointing to something that might be causing this issue.